# Cannot GET /page after page reload in MEAN Stack App

Tags: node.js, mean

I've push my MEAN Stack project to [Heroku](https://heroku.com/) with custom domain. Everything is running well when I try to check every route. But when I reload the page, or when I access some page using URL of that route, it return :

> Cannot GET /page

How it can happen? And how is the solving? Thank you.

This is my app.js file if needed :

```
const express   = require('express');
const path      = require('path');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const passport  = require('passport');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const config    = require('./config/database');
const port      = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const cors      = require('cors');
const app       = express();
const users     = require('./routes/users');
const companies = require('./routes/companies');
const reports   = require('./routes/reports');

app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(config.database);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
    console.log('Connected to ' +config.database);
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log('Unable to Connect ' +config.database);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/reports', reports);
app.use('/companies', companies);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('Index Page');
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server Running on Port : '+port)
});
```

Comment: May I see you local /page look like ?

Comment: /page is not exist. /page just just common variable example, the truth pages like : /admin , /dashboard , /profile etc. When I insert an URL to address bar like this : www.mydomain.com/admin , it returns Cannot GET /admin. But when I do in localhost:4200/admin, it is run well.

Comment: And when I reload at www.mydomain.com/admin, it return Cannot GET /admin. But when I reload at localhost:4200/admin, it is also work fine.

Comment: I think you should make a middleware in order for your app to be able avoid Get/ error. You can visit my mean stack app here for further detail https://github.com/ngohungphuc/TDT-Forum/tree/master/Source/Web

Answer (score 1):

So assuming this is an SPA, you most likely have client-side routes which do not exist on the server, this is deliberate and one of the main benefits of creating an SPA (no page refreshes). However, as a consequence the problem then exists where if you refresh whilst on one of these routes the server will fail because the route can't be matched.

To fix, you need to ensure the route that serves the client app *always* serves the app (outwith any existing server URLs of course). In express, this can be achieved by using a wildcard param in the URL pattern i.e.

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.send('Index Page'));
```

This will match any path, from the root URL, that doesn't match any of the previously configured URLs - so in the case of your example if you refresh on `/page` your app should render.

Comment: I've try this. When I reload www.mydomain.com/dashboard, it returns Index Page.

Comment: @MuhammadFatihRizqon yes, that's what I would expect - as per my answer, I presume this is an SPA you are building? It's up to the client to then handle the `/page` route.

Answer (score 0):

You set router try the following and push commit to heroku again.

```js
app.get('/page',function(req,res){
  res.send("page");
});
```

Comment: I don't think so, when I try to running on localhost, everything is alright. I mean, when I try to reload the page or using URL to access some page, it isn't return "Cannot GET /" error message. This error just happen when I push it to Heroku.

Comment: or should I change the '/' to '/domainname' ??

Comment: you have create a Procfile file upload Heroku?

Comment: What is procfile? I'm so sorry, I'm new with Heroku. Forgive for my bad.

Comment: You create Procfile in root upload to heroku, to run app.js file on heroku,in file you write,            web: node app.js

Comment: I've created the Procfile, but it still return Cannot GET / after reloaded the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a MERN app and deploying it in heroku...
I was also getting same error "cannot get /page" whenever I did refresh or window.location()
So after 3 days of trials and deploys I found this solution.
Add this in your server.js file before deploying.

```
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
      });
}
```

You can add this code snippet before app.listen. Remember the path says ./client/build/index.html which references to your build file in the production build in remote heroku master.

cannot get /page happens because the server is not able to find the route which was created using react-router or anything else in frontend so we need to direct the app to index.html in production build so that it starts the whole frontend process again and identifies the route...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Whats the __dirname here @Saurav?